# Defining width of page in section, rather than in body

Tags: html, css

I want my page to have a fix width, lets say 1440px. I usually put width in body and it applies to all elements. In my new project I need to have one section in white background, width being fixed makes it so that only 1440px is white. I managed to solve this by removing width from body and creating a class:

```css
.width-fix {
  width: 144rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.2rem;
}
```

I set that class as additional to every section I don't needed colored.

Is this the right way to solve it or is there something better? Currently it works like a charm.

I started learning HTML/CSS 2 weeks ago, sorry if its dumb question

**Edit: Image for clarification
[image]

Comment: it's a strange question. If you set the width on content (sections) instead of body, the size of the body will depend on its content, otherwise will just be set by the container. So there's nothing wrong to have your sections styled like that I just have doubts on what's the real problem you want to address by doing that. Because when you talk about the background that's another matter.. if you have a body background red for example and you want your sections with a different bg, you should set it in your style

Comment: The need is not clear, but since you started learning HTML/CSS I can advise you to start learning bootstrap as well, it will help you a lot.

Comment: @DiegoD I edited first post to add image. You can see the white and "purple" sections. Setting width in body would shrink the white section to fixed width, but I wanted container to be fully white as in picture. My solution as described above works, I was just wondering if its the correct one or I need to change something up. Thanks for response, cheers

Comment: @amel I am planning to learn either Bootstrap or Tailwind. I just wanted to create couple of quick projects to get a handle on flexbox/css grid. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: it's hard to understand why having a fixed width on elements like section or body in a responsive page in 2022... anyway in terms of how to do things properly, ***usually*** (and in a page like the one you showed in the thumbnail) the body width: should have no horizontal scrollbar; should take care of things like padding and layout (if not left to following nested containers); and the sections should size horizontally according to their container. You keep talking about the background.. but if any given section needs its own background, just override it in its style.

Comment: then if the problem becomes that you wanted the section to have  background filling the full width then just go with width:100% but let the body rule the fixed master width so you have one place only (unless you are using custom properties)

Comment: @DiegoD Okay understood. Thank you for the clarification, I will be looking into changing it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, usually I work with a classname like container or section for all the most general default styling.
Every element is packed in a section which holds the right background-color and has a div with container for the right width and margins and padding.

So something like this:

```
  .block {
 background-color: green;
 }
 .container {
 max-width: 1440px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 25px;
 }
 <section class="block">
 <div class="container">
 
 </div>
 </section>
```